# Climbing CFData memory usage when using Core Image filters

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc, core-image, cfdata

I'm having a problem with too much allocated  memory. My app alloc mem reaches up to 100MB!
And yes... i'm using `ARC`. most of memory allocated is by `CFData`(as i understand it is `CoreImage` filters). After applying filter to image, `CFData` allocated memory goes up by ~1.3mb and does not deallocate:

[image: Instruments showing the memory usage]

The code looks like this:

```
+(UIImage*)BWFilter:(UIImage *)imgFX
{
    CIImage *sourceImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:imgFX];

    CIImage *blackAndWhite = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, sourceImage, @"inputBrightness", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"inputContrast", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1], @"inputSaturation", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], nil].outputImage;
    CIImage *output = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIExposureAdjust" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, blackAndWhite, @"inputEV", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7], nil].outputImage;

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgiimage = [context createCGImage:output fromRect:output.extent];
    imgFX = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiimage];

    if (cgiimage) {
        CGImageRelease(cgiimage);
    }

    return imgFX;
}
```

The memory usage doesn’t go down after a memory warning, so it should not be a cache issue.

Comment: How are you storing the returned image?

Comment: Or, in other words, how does the calling code look like? The code sample in the question looks fine. Also, what does the Leaks instrument say?

Comment: Have you run the static analyzer?  Product > Analyze.  Does it give you any diagnostics?

Comment: Static analyzer gives me nothing. And leaks instrument does not  show any leaks.  http://pastebin.com/wDJhzu4G I call ReDraw method in order to redraw all filters stored in the list.

Comment: I as i understand CGImageRelease(cgimg); is not working  after  first time you apply the filter, because it does not release the image created by  cgimg  = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on a sample project (with ARC) and it does not give any leaks nor extra allocations. `CFData` is not essentially related to `CIFilter` subclasses but to the `CIImage`. Problem is somewhere else.